# Change the value of a static variable inside of a static function in PHP

Tags: php, static

In **php** if I have a static variable inside of a static class method:

```
class Functions {
    public static function fetch_id() {
       static $id;

       ....
    }
}
```

Can I change the value of the static $id from outside? I.E. is it possible to do:

```
Functions::$id = 'something new';
```

Comment: You can't variables that are local to a function from outside, whether they're static or not.

Comment: So it is not possible to change $id without passing a new value into it `Functions::fetch_id('something new')`.

Comment: Of course not. (Aside from it reading a db or something in the function.) The real question is why you would want to change the value of a variable in a function by any means other than a parameter to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it was possible it would be a bad idea because it would be difficult to tell who, where, when changed the value. After all a local variable is a local variable.

If you want global access you either place it in the global context or provide a way to set/get that local variable.

If you don't want to always pass a new value you could have an if statement inside that method like this:

```
class Functions {
    public static function fetch_id($arg=null) {
       static $id=null;
       if($arg!==null){
           $id=$arg;
           return null;
       }
       if( $id===null ){
           return false;
       }
       return $id;
    }
}
```